# How to pull master from a branch that was reverted without deleting files

Tags: git, github

I have a branch that I pull requested. It was merged but then reverted with GitHub revert. Now if I pull master from that commit, it deletes all of the new files.

So in other words, I created a branch called `newbranch`, made a new file called `file.txt`, and then pull requested. It was merged, but then reverted using Github revert. Now if I check out that branch and pull master, it says:

`delete mode 100644 file.txt`

How do I start from this commit, pull master, and not have it delete the changes here?

Thanks!

Comment: "pull master, and not have it delete the changes here" - this is something of a contradiction - master now includes the deletion.  You could, of course, revert the revert!

Comment: Interesting, so if you have a branch that gets merged into master then reverted, there's no way to continue working on that branch while pulling master on occasion to keep it up to date.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what scenario you're describing.  Are you trying to continue work on `master`, or on `newbranch`?  If it's the latter, then why does it matter what's happening on `master`?

Comment: I'm trying to work on `newbranch`, and I want to pull master in order to keep `newbranch` up to date, because changes are happening rapidly, and if master gets too far ahead then it will be difficult to merge `newbranch` in the future.

Comment: Oh right, you want to *merge* changes from `master` into `newbranch`?  This workflow (merging branches into each other and continuing to work on both) is slightly dubious - generally it leads to a confusing mess.  But the same principle applies; you could revert the commit after you've merged from `master` into `newbranch`.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Didn't realize that was a dubious workflow. I guess I can manually recreate the changes in my old branch and start from there.

Comment: The best bet is to start a new branch - model your branches as [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) whose lifetime ends once they're merged into the mainline.  On that new branch (`newnewbranch`??), you can perform any changes you like, including a revert of the previous deletion.

Comment: Looks like an awesome tutorial, very pleasant to the eyes. I'll check it out!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I had - a feature branch. The only problem is that it got merged into master prematurely, so it was reverted. Now if I keep working on the original branch, it deletes the files. How do I revert the previous deletion, keeping in mind that it's now many days later and master has been updated quite a bit.